# How to get all the items in a dictionary from a function

Tags: python, dictionary

The function below returns the contents of the dictionary. Aside from returning the content of the dictionary, how to get all the names of the dict inside the function?

```
def get_ext(file_type):
    xsds = {'this is 1st': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
    rsksd = {'this is 2nd': ['1', '2', '3', '4']}
    as2w = {'this is 3rd': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
    return locals()[file_type]

print (get_ext("xsds"))

# Output
{'this is 1st': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
```

Needed Output:

```
xsds
rsksd
as2w
```

Comment: `list(locals())` will return the names of all the local variables in the function.

Comment: Why does the function take an argument that names a specific variable if you want to return all of them?

Comment: I am using the specific name of the variable but also needs to check if the variable I want is there.

Comment: If you just want to prevent an exception, you can use `.get(file_type)` instead of `[file_type]`

Comment: `return dict(xsds={..}. rsksd={...}, as2w={...})[file_type]`; no need for `locals`.